# useEffect inside a Class component to Scroll on top of page

Tags: reactjs, render, use-effect

I normally use this code to scroll on top of the page in my function but this time I need this in my class component, how can I do that

```
    class MyPage extends Component {
        render() {
            useEffect(() => {
                window.scrollTo(0, 0)
            }, []);
           
            return (
                .......
            (
        }

    }
```

Comment: useEffect is react hooks that just can you use for functional component, then you can used componentDidMount lifecycle in class component

Answer (score 2):

You can write this

```
class MyPage extends Component {

   componentDidMount(){
     window.scrollTo(0, 0)
   }

 render(){
      return (
            .......
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: But isnt it that `componentDidMount` is for react older version?

Comment: If you want to replicate the same behaviour as useEffect in class component then you have to use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)